# Получить неоднородные данные одним запросом в MS SQL Server Report Builder

Tags: sql, sql-server

Допустим, у меня есть таблица со с товарами, записи которой мне нужно получить. Поля такого рода:

```
id
name
price
```

Возможно ли получить не стандартный набор данных вида

```
Помидор 50
Огурец  47
Морковь 30
```

А дополнительно вывести, например, такое

```
Помидор          50
Огурец           47
Помидор + Огурец 97
Морковь          30
```

Как это сделать внутри одного и того же запроса, понятия не имею.

Comment: Не надо "например". Сформулируйте ТОЧНО И ОДНОЗНАЧНО задачу - тогда и можно будет обсуждать пути её решения. Ещё лучше - дополнительно создайте fiddle с данными и покажите результат ДЛЯ ЭТИХ ДАННЫХ с пояснением, почему так. PS. *Возможно ли получить* - да.

Comment: Реальные задачи намного сложнее, ссылаются на внешние таблицы и представления, но суть того, что мне нужно, я изложил в такой простой форме, как я считаю. Мне бы банально понять, как в выборку добавить сумму двух элементов. P.S. Пытался сделать фиддл, но не получилось, прошу прощения

Comment: Форма, может, и простая, но совершенно невменяемая. Почему из всех пара образована только одна, а не все три  теоретически возможные?

Comment: Привел пример, максимально приближенный к моей задаче. Мне буквально нужно выдать всего одну пару вместе с обычной выборкой

Comment: *Мне буквально нужно выдать всего одну пару вместе с обычной выборкой* И компьютер должен по некоему мистическому наитию угадать, какую из трёх потенциально возможных пар тебе нужно... не, ну должен же быть предел маразму! Какие есть исходные данные, которые позволяют **точно и однозначно** установить, что "Помидор + Огурец", а остальные пары - нет?